# What is the ‘A' role?

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography

In fact the running is fail if using code[A]. I don't understand why.Also I don't understand that first -'A' then +'A'.Why the [A] is fail? [B] is well?

```
Code [A]  (char) (ch + key) % 26 )
Code [B]  (char) ('A' + ((ch -'A' + key) % 26))

public void run() {

        setFont("Arial-PLAIN-24");
        String line = readLine ("Enter line: ");
        int key = readInt ("Enter key: ");

        String siphertext = encryptCaesar(line , key);

        println("The result is: " + siphertext);

        String newplain = encryptCaesar(siphertext , -key);
        println("newplain:" + newplain);

    }

    private String encryptCaesar(String str , int key){
        if(key < 0){
            key = 26 - ( -key % 26 );
        }

        String result = "";
        for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++){
            char ch = str.charAt(i);        
            result += encryptChar(ch,key);
        }
        return result;
    }
    /**Why can't use ( (ch + key) % 26 )*/

    private char encryptChar(char ch, int key){
        if(Character.isUpperCase(ch)){
            return ( (char) ('A' + ((ch -'A' + key) % 26)) );
        }
        return ch;
    }
```

Comment: Please be more clear with what you are trying to ask.

Comment: We cannot know why you cannot do certain things. It would help if you told us how you tried, and what happened when you tried, so we could help you.

Comment: @BheshGurung That's easy.  He wants to know why is fail if using `code[A]`!

Answer (score 2):

If I understand what you are asking...

The function of the `'A'` here is to convert a character into a number that corresponds to its ordinal position in the alphabet.

The expression `(ch -'A' + key) % 26` will yield a value in the range 0 to 25 depending on the ordinal position of the character and the value of the key variable.

Comment: I don't understand that first -'A' then +'A'.Why the [A] is fail? [B] is well?

Comment: The running is fail if using [A].I don't understand 'A' role in [B].

Answer (score 1):

Well the [A] form gives a value between `0` and `25` inclusive, and the [B] form gives you a value between `'A'` and `'Z'` inclusive.  They are clearly not the same expression.

---

And if you read the two forms in this light, the first use of `'A'` in the [B] form is to make sure that the result value stays in the range `'A'` through `'Z'`.

The second use where `'A'` is subtracted is needs to properly implement Caesar encryption.  If you remove it you will end up with a different encryption.  (The `- 'A'` ensures that `key` selects the `key`th rotation of the alphabet.  Without it, your `encryptCaesar(a, key)` will actually calculate `real_caesar(a, (key - 64) % 26)`; i.e. a Caesar encryption with a different key.)

But this should all be obvious if you "hand execute" the two versions of the code to see how they map the input characters to output characters.